# When is a Ljung-Box test significant?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, stationarity

I have trouble understanding the output of the Ljung-Box test due to conflicting information:

The R documentation doesn't actually say how to interpret the output.

[This site](http://www.statosphere.com.au/check-time-series-stationary-r/) states that small p-values means that the data is likely to be stationary.

This [otexts textbook](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/6) states that large p-values means that the data is likely to be like white noise.

Clearly, one of them must be wrong. Which one is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is simply wrong. If you just check the wiki on L-B test, you will see that the null hypothesis is that the data are White Noise, so small $p$-values (say $<0.05$) mean that you have evidence to reject the null hypothesis. Here is a good online [reference](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ljung-box-test/). Moreover, if you would like to test your data for white noise, in addition to this, I could suggest you try our [hwwntest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hwwntest/index.html) package which contains several types of white noise tests with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct because if we are doing the manual problem the p- value <0.05 means that we can accept the null hypothesis but in softwares such as SPSS  and R if the p- value < 0.05 means that we can  reject the null hypothesis because the table value which we used for manual problem is different for softwares.

Comment: This sounds very surprising! Can you explain it better, or back it up with references?